# Tomcat fails when adding J2ee.jar. I need to javax.persistence to connect JDBC from persistence.xml.I need to have j2ee.jar under tomcat.

Tags: tomcat

How do I configure to add j2ee.jar under tomcat (or) how do I make javax.persistence to work by adding j2ee.jar under tomcat